# Magento2 : How to change Email Sender for Sub Website

Tags: magento-2.1.7, multi-website

I have created two website in my Magento2 CMS, also changed all `Store Email Addresses` for Sub Website Store view, but still in mails from sub website (like `order confirmation, new account email`) sender id is coming from default config setting.

How do I do change all sender email in sub website?

Comment: Ensure you update your system cache.

Comment: Yes, I did, ran `cache:clean`, `cache:flush` and `setup:di:compile` commands after update config changes.

Answer (score 0):

Pleas configure every store by going to: `Shop -> Configure`

**Then switch store view in bar (upper left corner).**

Then go to `Store Email Addresse` and change it according to needs. Check other sections as: `Sales -> Sales Emails` , `Client -> Customer Configuration - Tab sender` etc.

Comment: I didn't find `Shop -> Configure` menu in backend. Can you please post a screenshot?